# Test if a datepicker has a value

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have a two datapickers, d1 and d2. 
There is a filter function that should filter by d1 only, d2 only or both d1 and d2.

```
@FXML
DatePicker d1;
@FXML
DatePicker d2;

public void filter(){
  SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

  String st = ft.format(ft.parse(this.d1.getValue().toString())));
  String en = ft.format(ft.parse(this.d2.getValue().toString())));

  if(st == null && en != null)
    filterbySt(d1);
  else
    filterbyEn(d2);
}
```

**If d1 or d2 are not set, *I get a null pointer exception***

How do I test if a datepicker has not been set ?

Answer (score 4):

### Problem

If d1/d2 ae not set, `d1.getValue()` returns `null` and using `d1.getValue().toString()` will throw `NullPointerException`.

### Solution

Just put a `null check` before you try to get the value out of the datepicker. If `datePicker.getValue()` is `null`, it implies *datepicker has not been set*

```
...
String st, en =null;
if(d1.getValue() != null){
  st = ft.format(ft.parse(this.d1.getValue().toString())));
}
if(d2.getValue() != null){
  en = ft.format(ft.parse(this.d2.getValue().toString())));
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also tried catching the nullPointer exception like this

```
  //catching the null pointer exception and moving on.
    String st = null, en = null;
    try{
        st = ft.format(ft.parse(this.d1.getValue().toString())));
    }catch(NullPointerException ex) {}

    try{
         en = ft.format(ft.parse(this.d2.getValue().toString())));
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){}
```